# Rich Text Editor for ReactNative applications

Tags: android, ios, react-native, rich-text-editor

Is there any Rich Text editor plugins to support iOS and Android applications? apart from ZSS RichTextEditor plugin (https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor)

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: try this one  https://github.com/wix/react-native-zss-rich-text-editor ?

Comment: or this one  https://github.com/HoneyBook/react-native-richtext-editor

Comment: Cannot use both. Honeybook cannot support Android.:-(

Comment: even the first one from Wix? it says it supports both Ios and Android

Comment: In my application, i cannot change react-native-webview in my app..so i cannot use ZSS RichTextEditor